# Add dir to List DirectoryInfo

Tags: c#

how to add new directory to List

```
public static List<DirectoryInfo> Directory = new List<DirectoryInfo>(); 

Directory.Add("C:\\test"); // error  'string' to 'System.IO.DirectoryInfo'
```

Comment: An aside, but you should avoid exposing public fields. It is better to expose it as a property, and in this case most likely one limited to a get

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [DirectoryInfo constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.directoryinfo.aspx) which allows you to pass a string which represents the path:

```
Directory.Add(new DirectoryInfo("C:\\test"));
```